# Finding the 'closed' form of this exponential generating function

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

The exponential generating function of this recurrence relation, $T_n=T_{n-1}\;+(n-1)\cdot T_{n-2}\;$, is

$$f(x)=e^{x + \frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Multiplying the exponential generating functions for each term, we get,
$$=\ \sum_{j\geq0}\;\frac{1}{j!}x^j\cdot\sum_{k\geq0}\;\frac{1}{2^kk!}x^{2k}$$
$$=\ \sum_{j,\ \ k\geq0}\;\frac{1}{j!}\cdot\frac{1}{2^kk!}x^{j+2k}$$

Taking $n\ =\ j\ +\ 2k$,
$$=\ \sum_{n-2k,\ \ k\geq0}\;\frac{1}{(n-2k)!}\cdot\frac{1}{2^kk!}x^n$$

What steps can I take from here to get to the 'closed' form of the exponential generating function, i.e.,

$$\;\sum_{n\ge0}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\frac{n!}{(n-2k)!2^kk!}\Big)\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set
$$
a_{2k}  = \frac{1}{{2^k k!}},\quad a_{2k + 1}  = 0
$$
for $k\geq 0$, then
$$
\!\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{j!}}x^j } } \right)\!\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{2^k k!}}x^{2k} } } \right) = \left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{j!}}x^j } } \right)\!\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {a_k x^k } } \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{1}{{(n - k)!}}a_k } } \right)x^n } .
$$
Now it remains to simplify
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{1}{{(n - k)!}}a_k }.
$$
Since the terms corresponding to even $k$'s contribute only, we put $k=2m$ where $m$ runs between $0$ and $\left[ n/2 \right]$ (in this way we took into account all the even $k$'s between $0$ and $n$). Thus,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{1}{{(n - k)!}}a_k }  = \sum\limits_{m = 0}^{\left[ {n/2} \right]} {\frac{1}{{(n - 2m)!}}a_{2m} }  = \sum\limits_{m = 0}^{\left[ {n/2} \right]} {\frac{1}{{(n - 2m)!}}\frac{1}{{2^m m!}}} .
$$
Hence, the exponential generating function is
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{\left[ {n/2} \right]} {\frac{1}{{(n - 2m)!2^m m!}}} } \right)x^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{\left[ {n/2} \right]} {\frac{{n!}}{{(n - 2m)!2^m m!}}} } \right)\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}} .
$$

Comment: Since the terms with $a_{2k}$ contribute only, replace $k$ with, say, $2m$ in my last expression. If $0\leq k\leq n$, then $0\leq m \leq\ldots$ Can you see it? Also you have to divide $x^n$ by $n!$ in your very last line. Otherwise it is not an exponential generating function.

Comment: I just had another question, how did $$\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{j!}}x^j } } \right)\!\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{2^k k!}}x^{2k} } } \right)$$ change to this  $$= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{1}{{(n - k)!}}a_k } } \right)x^n }$$ What happened to $x^{2k}\;$? I'm  a bit new to summation, so it'll be great if you could help me out...

Comment: There is an extra step inbetween. Take that into account and then apply the Cauchy product of the two series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series This answer of mine was accepted and upvoted before, wan't it?

Comment: Okay, so I spent some time figuring out the Cauchy product, but to no avail.. Could you please show the steps for the Cauchy product you've applied? You can do so in the comments section if you want. I've struggled with this for quite a long time (haven't learned this in school, just an exploration). I hope I'm not bothering you.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not really understand what the issue is here. Just use $$
\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\alpha _j x^j } } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\beta _k x^k } } \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\alpha _{n - k} \beta _k } } \right)x^n } .
$$ In our case $\alpha_j=1/j!$ and $\beta_k =a_k$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the concept. However, I still haven’t understood this statement - “Since the terms corresponding to even $k$'s contribute only, we put $k=2m$ where $m$ runs between $0$ and $\left[ n/2 \right]$ (in this way we took into account all the even $k$'s between $0$ and $n$)”… Why do only even $k$’s contribute?

Comment: Because for odd $k$, $a_k=0$ (by definition).